# 'express differently' exercise problem

Tags: grammar

exercise: it's a pity you don't speak German 
=>if only you could speak German (1)
=>if only you spoke German       (2) 
Which answer is correct ?And why ? 
Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It is "if only you could speak German"

The subtle difference is likely to be that one who can speak German need not speak German. One who can speak it, say German words out loud, may or may not be "able to" speak German, understand and express themselves.

The initial sentence expresses sadness that since you do not speak German you cannot understand some point. It is not the question of your actually speaking German, saying German words, but of your ability to speak it meaning speak and understand.